# Display page data on same page without forwarding it to another page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts-1

In my webpage (Eg Link1: http://localhost:8086/MyStrutsApp/login.do) I have several links. When a user clicks on one of the links, he is taken to another page (Eg link2: http://localhost:8086/MyStrutsApp/AddBook.jsp) to fill an html form.

Now what I want to achieve is that when any user clicks on the link, that html form (Link2) is displayed on the same page (i.e. Link1).

I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? A page where two diffrent pages have diffrent urls is easier to understand by persons and also google. Thinka bout this page for example, stackoverflow.com, and how diffrent pages has diffrent urls.

Comment: @vistige: But also here we have the "add comment" which lets us add a comment without leaving the page, and we can add an answer without going to a new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AJAX way to achieve this is the following:

- you have a DIV on your original page that will be replaced (i.e., either has content that only makes sense in the original context or completely empty)
- your Link2 servlet produces only the contents of the above DIV (and not the contents of that page)
- you use a tiny bit of Javascript to make an AJAX call and fill the DIV with the response.

If you want to use Dojo, the HTML page would look like this:

```
<!-- main content -->
<div id="leftpanel">
    <h3>This content will be replaced</h3>
    You can <a href="#" onClick="updateFromURL('/MyStrutsApp/AddBook.jsp)">add a book</a>
</div>
```

The Javascript code would look like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_wait(s) {
  var mainPanel=dojo.byId("leftpanel");
  mainPanel.innerHTML='<div class="waitingmsg">'+s+'</div>';
}

function updateFromURL(url) {
    display_wait("loading content");
    dojo.xhrGet({url:url,
                load:function(result) {
                dojo.byId('leftpanel').innerHTML=result;
            }});
}
</script>
```

(As Rafa mentioned, you can use the same technique to display the new part in a dialog)

Comment: if u can plz take a look at this [link](http://pastebin.com/CHGVS81r)  and [link](http://pastebin.com/0QxbLhrU)   i used urs script but when i click on `add a book` i want (This content will be replaced) text to be replaced by form2.html data i.e its html form but its not happening...

Comment: It works fine for me - you need to load the HTML files via a HTTP server, though, it does not work if you just point the browser at the file URL. (You can use something like "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" to simply serve files from the current directory, if you just want to try something out)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use jQuery to present a dialog ... http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Retrieve the page with AJAX and present it inside the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To display one page within another, use an `iframe`.  See the [iframe docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/iframe).

To make a link on the outer page load its target page into the `iframe`, give the `iframe` a `name` attribute, and give the link a matching `target` attribute.